# Memory management for NSURLConnection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, nsurlconnection

Sorry if this has been asked before, but I'm wondering what the best memory management practice is for `NSURLConnection`.  Apple's sample code uses `-[NSURLConnection initWithRequest:delegate:]` in one method and then `release`s in `connection:didFailWithError:` or `connectionDidFinishLoading:`, but this spits out a bunch of analyzer warnings and seems sort of dangerous (what if neither of those methods is called?).

I've been autoreleasing (using `+[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:delegate:]`), which seems cleaner, but I'm wondering--in this case, is it ever possible for the `NSURLConnection` to be released before the connection has closed (for instance, when downloading a large file)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This returns autoreleased `NSURLConnection`:**

```
+[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:delegate:]
```

If you want to keep the reference you need to `retain` it. Once you are done then `release` it.
It does not help to `autorelease` already `autorelease`d object.

I assume the example code will somewhere `retain` the `NSURLConnection` and then `release` it when the connection fails, as shown in your example.

This returns allocated object that you have to take care of cleaning

```
-[NSURLConnection initWithRequest:delegate:]
```

Because the method is named `init`, the other one above does not have `init` in the name or `copy` so you don't have to worry about the memory management.

If your object internally creates `NSURLConnection` at some point and then `release`s it when connection is done or failed you should reset the reference to nsurlconnection to `nil`.

In your `dealloc` you should cleanup the `NSURLConnection` as well, if it is `nil` nothing will happen but if it is still allocated it will clean it up.

See [apple doc about memory management](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html) - it's quite simple.

Comment: Thanks, I was asking more specifically--is it safe to just autorelease it (i.e., would it be possible for the `NSURLConnection` to be released by the autorelease pool before it's actually finished)?